# How to check if async/await really async?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, async-await, c#-5.0

I have built a certain application( service ) based on `async/await` new keywords in c# 5.0 using **`WebApi`** which it self cool, I have create a call from Oracle db `Http_Request`, but i have tested and it's not really feels right, how can I unit test the **`async`** matter if this?

```
public async Task<WebResponse> Post(Customer customer)
{
        if (!customer.ReturnSuccess()) throw new ArgumentNullException("customer");
        _logger.Info(string.Format("Customer validation request - date = {0} \n {1}\t\n", DateTime.Now, customer));
        try
        {
            return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => _service.EvaluateCustomer(customer));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.ErrorException("Error", e);
        }
        return null;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't “feel right”? What exactly do you want to test?

Comment: P.S. You should use `Task.Run` instead of `Task.Factory.StartNew` in `async` code.

Comment: @svick the response is sync and not async, so my question is can i test it for asynchronous?

Comment: @StephenCleary can you explain?

Comment: [Stephen Toub has all the details here.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx) In summary: `Task.Run` has more reasonable default parameters, and it understands `async` methods.

Comment: Thanks I will read it. But it's not answering my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Cheburek in general: don't waste your time unit testing things like `await` and `Task.Run`.

However, if you want to ensure *your* method is properly waiting for `EvaluateCustomer`, then you inject a service that is under your control and ensure `Post` only completes after `EvaluateCustomer` completes:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task PostWaitsForEvaluateCustomer()
{
  var finishEvaluateCustomer = new ManualResetEvent(false);
  var service = new MyFakeService(finishEvaluateCustomer)
  {
    EvaluateCustomer = _ => finishEvaluateCustomer.WaitOne();
  };
  var objectUnderTest = new MyObject(service);

  Task postTask = objectUnderTest.Post(..);
  Assert.IsFalse(postTask.IsCompleted);

  finishEvaluateCustomer.Set();
  await postTask;
}
```

Comment: Thank you I will start testing it.

Answer (score 2):

Do not Unit Test language features - they are already tested by someone who has much more money than you. Test your business logic instead.

Read msdn about async/await behaviour here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh156513.aspx

> The method runs **synchronously** until it reaches its first await
>   expression, at which point the method is suspended until the awaited
>   task is complete. In the meantime, control returns to the caller of
>   the method, as the example later in this topic shows.

Comment: Privet! I don't wan't to test async/await I want to test my method.

Comment: @lamStalker I would suggest to test synchronous things - _service.EvaluateCustomer method in this case.

Comment: How this will help me? I know the method us synchronous